# ODE with periodic initial/end condition

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Are there any existence/uniqueness results for solutions to the ODE
$$y'(t) = f(y(t),t)$$
$$y(0) = y(T) = y_0$$
on the time interval $[0,T]$ where $f$ is Caretheodory and $y_0$ is given.

I am looking for $y \in C^0$ say and $y' \in L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe not.

There are existence/uniqueness results for solutions to the ODE
$$
y'(t) = f(y(t),t) \\
y(0) =y_0
$$
Adding an extra condition, you lose most of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There are some results, but usually the initial value $y_0$ is not known *a priori*. Here is an example. Suppose that there exist two constants $a<b$ such that

1. $f(b,t)\le0$ ($y(t)=b$ is a supersolution.)
2. $f(a,t)\ge0$ ($y(t)=a$ is a subsolution.)

Denote by $y(t,y_0)$ the solution of the initial value problem $y'=f(y,t)$, $y(0)=y_0$. If $y_0\in[a,b]$, then $a\le y(t,y_0)\le b$ for all $t$ where he solution is defined. Under mild conditions on $f$, the map $y_0\to y(T,y_0)$ is continuous and takes $[a,b]$ into itself. Thus it has a fixed point, that is, there exists $y_0\in[a,b]$ such that $y_0=t(T,y_0)$.